# Jquery script to type script

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript. Can someone help me how to write the below code in TypeScript? Also, I like to know how to call this on anchor tag `href`.

```
$('#theCarousel').carousel({
    // logic
})

<a href="#theCarousel"  class="custom" />
```

Comment: Hi.. I am new to typescript. Can someone help me how to write the below code in typecripst! Also, i like to know if how to call this on anchor tag href! Thanks in advance!

$('#theCarousel').carousel({
// logic
})

<a href="#theCarousel"  class="custom" />

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are stuck anywhere provide the code with complete error message.

Comment: This is how you write it in Typescript: `$('#theCarousel').carousel({
    /* logic */
})`